# Cannot extend native objects in a Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been trying to port a working Chrome WebExtension to the new Firefox WebExtension platform. My extension was rejected, and one of the reasons stated that:

> Extending the prototype of native objects like Object, Array and String is not allowed because it can cause compatibility problems with other add-ons or the browser itself.

This sounds odd. Doesn't each extension live within its own environment? If I extend String with .MyFavoriteFunction(), I don't expect all other web pages and extensions on the computer to be able to use it!